# Which Visual Studio Code Extension for Git Diff and Merge Tool?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Currently I have a third party app called Meld configured as Git Diff and Merge Tool. This is not optimal, as it's ugly and has a non-standard user interface and user experience, as all or most external diff and merge tools have.

Is there a Visual Studio Code Extension that plugs into the Git Diff and Merge Tool functionality, and is a native VSCode Extension at the same time? So I don't have to use third party external apps for diff and merge? Is such solution possible? Can someone point me to the correct Extension with this functionality?

This would be very clean I find.